# Gazebo fail to connect to master in 30 seconds. It does not run from the very first time

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to Gazebo as well as Ubuntu...
So dont have much knowledge about any of them.

I have been trying to install gazebo's latest version.
Step by step copying the lines from the installation guide to the terminal.

But at the end when i try to run gazebo it tells to wait for master and never connects to it.

Below is the terminal screen after i enter Gazebo.

=======================================================================================

salmaan@ubuntu:~$ gazebo

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.6

Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.

Released under the Apache 2 License.

http://gazebosim.o r g

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.6

Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.

Released under the Apache 2 License.

http://gazebosim.o r g

Msg Waiting for master.Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:331] Getting models

from[http://gazebosim.o r g/models/]. This may take a few seconds.

.............................

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:116] Failed to connect to master in 30 seconds.

Warning [gazebo_main.cc:57] escalating to SIGKILL on server

========================================================================================

Please help me out, as i will be doing my BCS final year project in this.
Path finding and obstacle detection.

Thanks in Advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65402/gazebo-fail-to-connect-to-master-in-30-seconds.-it-does-not-run-from-the-very-first-time./) by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5175/salmaanahmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-06-18**:
Please open one question per problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the following:

- `source /usr/share/gazebo-1.8/setup.sh`
- `gzserver`
- on a new shell run,`gzclient <your-world.sdf>`. If you run just gzclient, you will see the empty world.

There are many gazebo lovers here who can help you out but in future remember to post questions related to standalone gazebo on [answers.gazebosim.org](http://www.answers.gazebosim.org) or at least post a copy there.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5175/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thank you so very much it worked :)

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-08**:
@SalmaanAhmed please mark answer as correct if it helped you

**Comment by [Mark Silliman](https://answers.ros.org/users/20282/mark-silliman/) on 2014-12-01**:
Very helpful but gzserver should have the world not gzclient.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components&cat=get_started (at the bottom).

E.g.

gzserver <your-world.sdf>

then in new terminal

gzclient